# Subreport without group in DynamicJasper

Tags: dynamic-jasper

I would like set a subreport in DynamicJasper without group. When a put a group a new line is created. (See the image). I have tried to insert addConcatenatedReport, but show only subreport. I would like to put report a same line. Thanks!

[image: Report with subreport]

```
        FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
        drb.addColumn("Matrícula", "empMatr", Object.class.getName(), 5).addGroups(1)
                .addColumn("Nome", "pessoaFisica.pesNome", String.class.getName(), 10)
                .addColumn("Data Admissão", "dtAdmissao", Date.class.getName(), 5).setMargins(5, 5, 20, 20)
                .setWhenNoDataAllSectionNoDetail();

        drb.addField("familiares", List.class.getName());

        DynamicReport drFooterSubreport = createFooterSubreport();
        drb.addSubreportInGroupFooter(1, drFooterSubreport, new ClassicLayoutManager(), "familiares",
                DJConstants.DATA_SOURCE_ORIGIN_FIELD, DJConstants.DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_COLLECTION);

        drb.setUseFullPageWidth(true);
        DynamicReport dr = drb.build();

        JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(empregados);
        JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr, new ClassicLayoutManager(), ds);

        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jp, servletOutputStream);

        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
        context.responseComplete();
        context.renderResponse();
```

....

```
private DynamicReport createFooterSubreport() throws Exception {
        FastReportBuilder rb = new FastReportBuilder();
        DynamicReport dr = rb.addColumn("Nome Familiar", "famNome", String.class.getName(), 100)
                .addColumn("Iden", "famIden", Long.class.getName(), 100).setDefaultStyles(titleStyleSubReport,subTitleStyleSubReport, headerStyleSubReport, columnStyleSubReport).setMargins(5, 5, 20,20).setUseFullPageWidth(true).build();
        
return dr;
        }
```

Comment: The solution: .addGroups(1, GroupLayout.VALUE_FOR_EACH )

Comment: Hi, you mind taking a look ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615452/dynamicjasper-how-to-add-a-subreport-as-columns